# Suggestions for a good VBScript IDE

Tags: vbscript, ide

what would be a good IDE for VB Script ?
Currently using Notepad++. Also have Sublime Text, VS Code installed.

I was wondering if i could discover a hidden gem through stack overflow !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Brackets (free)
- VBSEdit (paid)
- Systemscripter (paid)